# Get an entity set by its type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a code which works in .Net 4.6 with EF6 but won't work with ef.core. Compiler reports

> No overload for method 'Set' takes 1 arguments (CS1501)

```
  Type type = Type.GetType("ContextName.SomeModel");
  if (type == null) return null;

   var entity = db.Set(type).Find(id);
```

Basically, I am getting an object by a string name.  How to achieve this in .core (v 2.0)?

My imports:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Shared.Web.MvcExtensions;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? Do you have an error message? What the compiler say?

Comment: It says that method Set doesn't have an overload which takes 1 argument.

Comment: How you create the `db`variable?

Comment: "var db = new MyDbContext()" and declaration as "public class MyDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EF Core expose only a generic method `Set<T>()`. There is no overload that takes the type as parameter like we will do by using `Set(Type type)` in EF 6.

It seems like you need to find a data from an entity set. EF Core just make it simple because it exposes some instance methods like `Find` directly into the `DbContext` class.

So the below code in EF 6

```
var entity = db.Set(type).Find(id);
```

Can be rewritten like below in EF Core like this:

```
var entity = db.Find(type, id);
```

Comment: I don't think EFC exposes such methods from `DbContext` to "make it simple" - there is just no other option because EFC simply has no non generic `DbSet` class

Comment: This works for things other than Find also. I needed the "Add(entity)" method.